# Determine if a property type is a generic type argument

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Say you have the class:

```
public class GenericModel<T1, T2>
{
    public T1 Model1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Model2 { get; set; }
}
```

How can you tell using reflection that the type of Model1 is generic argument T1 and the type of Model2 is generic argument T2?

I'm looking for a property or something that will tell me that Model1's type maps to `typeof(GenericModel<,>).GetGenericArguments()[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
var model1Type = typeof(GenericModel<,>).GetProperty("Model1").PropertyType;
var model2Type = typeof(GenericModel<,>).GetProperty("Model2").PropertyType;
```

Then the values of `model1Type.IsGenericParameter` & `model2Type.IsGenericParameter` will both be `true` indicating that you've got the generic parameter type for the properties.

Also, `model1Type.Name == "T1"` & `model2Type.Name == "T2"`.

---

If you have a specific instance, such as `var instance = new GenericModel<int, int>();`, then you can do this to get the generic name of a property out:

```
var instanceModel1TypeName =
    instance
        .GetType()
        .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        .GetProperty("Model1")
        .PropertyType
        .Name;

// instanceModel1TypeName == "T1"
```

Comment: How would you know then that model1Type is T1 and not T2 and that model2Type is T2 and not T1?

Comment: You don't need reflection for that.  You can verify that at design time just by looking at the code.

Comment: @rushonerok - The name of the return type is "T1" and "T2" respectively.

Comment: Its giving me the actual type name. I'm not seeing anything that will map it to a generic type argument.

Comment: @rushonerok - What do you mean by "actual type name"? The variables `model1Type` and `model2Type` are the types of the generic type arguments.

Comment: If you have GenericModel<int, string> then model1Type.Name == "int". it doesn't tell me what generic argument that is. You can kind of guess but if you have GenericModel<int, int> you could be wrong.